# Looking for sub-documents containing a field in a document's array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

Assuming I have the following `persons` collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("569d07a38e61973f6aded134"),
  "name": "john",
  "pets": [
    {
      "name": "spot",
      "type": "dog",
      "special": "spot eye"
    },
    {
      "name": "bob",
      "type": "cat",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("569d07a38e61973f6aded135"),
  "name": "susie",
  "pets": [
    {
      "name": "fred",
      "type": "cat",
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the persons who's pet(s) has a `special` field? I'm looking to have the returned `pets` array only contain the pets with a `special` field.

For example, the expected result from the collection above would be:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("569d07a38e61973f6aded134"),
  "name": "john",
  "pets": [
    {
      "name": "spot",
      "type": "dog",
      "special": "spot eye"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to implement this in hopefully one query with `pymongo`, although even just a working MongoDB or mongoose query would be lovely.

I've tried to start with:

```
db.persons.find({pets:{special:{$exists:true}}});
```

but that has returned 0 records, even though there should be some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array holds embedded documents, you can query for specific fields in the embedded documents using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation).

Without dot notation you are querying array documents for a complete match.

Try the following query:

```
db.persons.find({'pets.special':{$exists:true}});
```

Comment: Thanks. That indeed works in the `mongo` terminal but for some reason the following `pymongo` query returns the full arrays, including those without `special`: `mperson.find( {"pets.special": { "$exists":"true" }} )`. Any idea why?

Comment: Instead of the string "true", you need to use the python boolean True: mperson.find( {"pets.special": { "$exists": True }} )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** to get the desired result. Run the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.persons.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "pets.special": { "$exists": true }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,             
            "pets": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$pets",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$gt": [ "$$el.special", null ] },

                                    "$$el", false 
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("569d07a38e61973f6aded134"),
            "name" : "john",
            "pets" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "spot",
                    "type" : "dog",
                    "special" : "spot eye"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The operators that make a significant difference are the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators. The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `pets` array that has elements not related to the parent documents based on the existence of the `special` property, based on the conditional operator **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** which evaluates the expression returned by the comparison operator **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/#exp._S_gt)**.